# fetching value from table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ind_type | Index_val |
+----------+-----------+
| pcount   |         7 |
| ncount   |        15 |
+----------+-----------+
```

I wwant to get values of pcount and ncount:

what's wrong with this:

```
$p= $mysqli->query('SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type='pcount'');
   echo "$p";
```

Comment: The problem: It is bad. Read a tutorial. Or the [official doc examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

Comment: You need to escape your `''`'s. Use `""`'s on the outside or escape the character like `'\''`. You also need to `->fetch_object()` on your `$p` and access your variables through object notation.

Comment: `'SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type="pcount"'`

Comment: I added an example on my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE a = 'bob'");
foreach ($query->fetch_object() as $row) {
   echo $row->column1;
   echo $row->column2;
   echo $row->column3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$p= $mysqli->query("SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type='pcount'");
   while ($obj = $p->fetch_object()){echo $obj->Index_val;}
```

//use this

Comment: thanks bro, but it also gives error `[21:24:51.807] Error: Invalid JSON string: <br />
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2/ajax_graph_temp.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
 @ https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/4086f2e8fc632adc52e6d6795a5637a4/format+en,default,corechart.I.js:91`

Comment: yes because Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string.

Comment: you fetch the object for getting the values

Comment: while ($obj = $p->fetch_object()){echo $obj->Index_val;}